# Getting memory leak when uploading data to the server

Tags: objective-c

I am uploading the data to the server it was showing leak at:

```
 NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
if([aCustObj.messageTitle length]>0)
{
    printf("\n messageTitle.......%s",[aCustObj.messageTitle UTF8String]);
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.messageTitle] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
if([aCustObj.phoneNumber length]>0)
{
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phoneNo\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.phoneNumber] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}
if([aCustObj.userName length]>0)
{
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.userName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

if([aCustObj.audioDuration length]>0)
{
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"duration\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.audioDuration] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
if([aCustObj.imeiNumber length]>0)
{
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imei\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.imeiNumber] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
if([aCustObj.latitude length]>0)
{
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"latitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.latitude] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
if([aCustObj.longitude length]>0)
{
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"longitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.longitude] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

if([imageData length]>0)
{
    printf("\n Image..");
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:imageData];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
}
if([data length]>0)
{
    printf("\n audio..");
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"audio.caf\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    [postBody appendData:data];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
}

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];//Showing leak at this line.
```

Can anyone suggest me how to rectify this.

Thanks in advance,
Lakshmi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is running in a thread, make sure that you have an autoreleasepool set up. The data method of `NSMutableData` returns an autoreleased object, and that can only happen when there is an autoreleasepool for your thread.